# Put the correct paths in my Live Server Web Extension

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, visual-studio-code

Good morning, I have a problem about which route to put on the current server in the Live Server Web Extension, it is to mount a local server with PHP without the need to use Xampp or another web server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMmKo.png)

Of course I also installed the PHP Server Extension which is the one that lifts the server with PHP but when I run it it tells me: 'PHP not found'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTWBG.png)

I've already configured my path within the editor, but I can't find the correct path to put in this extension so that it allows me to get the server up once and for all.

I installed direct php and put it in a folder called PHP8 and in it, an Exercises(Ejercicios) Folder where I have my scripts that are the ones I want to build (Something similar to how Xampp is)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB2PW.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, please explain how this problem is related to Javascript, PHP, HTML, and CSS - or remove the tags that are not related to the core problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved.

1.Create the files or folders that we will use within the folder where PHP is installed (Similar to what happens with Xampp's Htdocs and WAMP's www)

2.When Visual Studio Code is opened, the entire folder must be imported, not just the file where we are going to work

3.We set the current server address with our file path, or folder and it works.